# Should I declare my byte[]

Tags: c#, resharper, declaration

I am checking my application for 'bad code' using `ReSharper`.

I have the following `if-statement`:

```
if (Utility.Compare(Utility.ExtractRangeFromArray(bufferRx, 0, bytesRead), new byte[] { U_EOT}))
{
   // EOT (End of transmission) received, break from while
   break;
}
```

`ReSharper` tells me to change: `new byte[]` to `new[]`

**My question:** What is the best option? And why shouldn't I declare the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what resharper is saying.

It is saying that the `byte` part is redundant - it is not needed as the compiler can infer it.

Best practice is to use what your team is using - use what is most readable.

In this case, it is reasonable to expect that this is a byte array (from the context of the other variable names and possibly the byte constant) - but if your team mates are not familiar with streams you may want to keep the `byte` declaration for clarity.

Comment: I don't know what programmers will read this code in the future, so I think I'am fine with just keep using new byte[], but you answered my question, so I will accept it when SO allows me too.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper is telling you to define array as [Implicitly Typed Array(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)

> You can create an implicitly-typed array in which the type of the
>   array instance is **inferred from the elements specified** in the
>   array initializer.

You can ignore it or adopt it, depends what you and your team is comfortable with.